# How to interpret the rule [namespace.udir]p2 in the c++ standard?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, using-directives, name-lookup

I'm a bit confused about the implications of [namespace.udir]p2. Consider the following program:

```
namespace X { int i = 1; }

namespace Y { using namespace X; }

int main() { i = 2; }
```

In it name-lookup for `i` in main fails (i tried with GCC, Clang and visual c++). This does not seem to agree with [namespace.udir]p2 (http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.dcl#namespace.udir-2):

> A using-directive specifies that the names in the nominated namespace
>   can be used in the scope in which the using-directive appears after
>   the using-directive. During unqualified name lookup
>   ([basic.lookup.unqual]), **the names appear as if they were declared in
>   the nearest enclosing namespace which contains both the
>   using-directive and the nominated namespace.** [ Note: In this context,
>   “contains” means “contains directly or indirectly”.  — end note ]

With my program I'm applying this rule for the name `i`, declared by `int i = 1;` in `X`, the following way:

- The using-directive: `using namespace X;`
- The nominated namespace: `X`
- The nearest enclosing namespace: The global namespace

Doesn't this imply that the unqualified name-lookup of `i` in `main` should find `X::i`? Why do I not get this result with any of the three compilers that I tried?

Comment: *"the names appear as if they were declared"* only applies to unqualified lookup within Y. This is what the first sentence says, *"names in the nominated namespace can be used **in the scope in which the using-directive appears**"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using-directives make names visible *in the scope in which they appear*. For example, [basic.scope.namespace]p1

> for each *using-directive* that nominates the member’s namespace, the member’s potential scope includes that portion of the potential scope of the *using-directive* that follows the member’s point of declaration

where *the scope of a name* is a part of the program where that name (the declaration of that name) can be found via *unqualified lookup*.

Similarly, in [namespace.udir]p2,

> A *using-directive* specifies that the names in the nominated namespace can be used in the scope in which the *using-directive* appears after the *using-directive*.

which basically says the same thing as the above quote.

In the OP, the *using-directive* appears in namespace-scope of namespace Y; `main` is outside that scope, hence the *using-directive* has no effect on name lookup performed inside `main`.

Comment: The term "scope" is unfortunately used in two distinct ways here; *the scope of a name* (as defined in my answer) and *namespace scope* (the part of the program where you can declare a name that has namespace scope; but referring to a single namespace).

Comment: Yeah, the standard sometimes confuses scope with declarative region. There is a c++ standard core language issue about this. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23630201/whats-the-difference-between-declarative-region-and-scope